# String Into Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to convert a string into a multidimentional array.

I've found many answers online but they expect you to have array keys etc...

**My String:**

> UserIds\n234234\n20053\n19928\n16325

I've tried the usual way:

```
$arr= array();
$arr = explode("\n", $string);
```

and i've also tried

```
$arr[] = explode("\n", $string);
```

but the result is always like this:

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(7) "UserIds" 
    [1]=> string(6) "234234" 
    [2]=> string(5) "20053" 
    [3]=> string(5) "19928" 
    [4]=> string(5) "16325" 
}
```

My Expected Result:

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "UserIds" } 
    [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(234234) } 
    [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(20053) } 
    [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(19928) } 
    [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(16325) } 
}
```

Comment: Of course explode doesn’t produce just any arbitrary data structure you can imagine. The first result is what _is_ to be **expected** here. The second thing you have shown might be what you _want_, but it is not explode’s job to provide anything like that. If you want that, you have to transform the explode result yourself accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do it could be to map the response using [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and wrap the items in an array:

```
$string = "UserIds\n234234\n20053\n19928\n16325";
$arr = array_map(function($x){return [$x];}, explode("\n", $string));
print_r($arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZEaqC)

Comment: add a is_numeric test to filter out the numbers so they can be converted to int type. not that it really matters in php

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Works perfectly!